# Compare value in Binary(64) column to value returned by HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'SomeString')

Tags: t-sql, password-hash

I have a PasswordHash field in my mssql database. I insert a hashed password (sha2-512) into that field. I then want to compare a login attempt, and I don't get anything in response.

Example:

```
insert into Users PasswordHash values (HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'Password1'))

Select * from users where PasswordHash = (HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', 'Password1'))
```

--nothing returns

Comment: Works for me (after correcting the syntax error in the `INSERT`): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c36e38fc1e6f08c0339e176b7a97cdd2

Comment: Nevermind, my procedure was taking an input parameter of datatype nvarchar. This was causing the issue. Thanks!